# jQuery Datatables Getting Showing 1 to NaN of NaN entries

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

i have used jQuery Datatable in my view as follow;

```
<table id="CategoryGrid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Description
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And the javascript code for Datatable;

```
    var catGrid = $('#CategoryGrid').dataTable({
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "@Url.Action("CategoriesGet")",
        "aoColumns": [
            {
                "sName": "CategoryId",
                "bSearchable": false,
                "bSortable": false,
                "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                    return '<a href=\"Company/Details/' + oObj.aData[0] + '\">View</a>';
                }
            },
            { "sName": "CategoryName" },
            { "sName": "CategoryDescription" }
        ]
    });
```

The returned JSON data is as follow;

```
{"sEcho":"1","iTotalRecords":10,"TotalDisplayRecords":10,"aaData":[["1","For Sale","asdfasdf"],["2","Jobs","asdfasdfasdf"],["3","Classes","asdfasdf"],["4","Vehicles","asdfasdsadfa"],["45","test","asdff"],["46","asfd","sdf"],["47","test","sdf"],["48","another test","sfsdfsdf"],["49","another test","sdfsdfsdf"],["50","asfd","asdf"]]}
```

**Why i am getting Showing 1 to NaN of NaN entries**

Comment: Make sure that the `sEcho` you replying back from the server is the one you just got from the client (*An unaltered copy*) , also you better cast it to `int`

Comment: but i am getting `sEcho`="1" from the server and in the string fromat as well

Comment: Also where is the *iiiiii* prefix of the `iTotalDisplayRecords` word ?

Comment: @Daniel, putting `i` fixed the prob but now i can't naviage next and previous i.e the paging isn't working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you got a typo in `iTotalDisplayRecords` word , you forgot the *i* letter prefix...

Also , take a look at this [Server-side processing](http://datatables.net/usage/server-side)

In general your reply from the server should contain: `iTotalRecords` , `iTotalDisplayRecords` , `sEcho` and `aaData` attributes...

> sEcho : An unaltered copy of sEcho sent from the client side. This parameter will change with each draw (it is basically a draw count) - so it is important that this is implemented. Note that it strongly recommended for security reasons that you 'cast' this parameter to an integer in order to prevent Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks.